# Node Mysql undefined field on multiple queries

Tags: mysql, undefined

1. I'm using node, express, mysql

   2. I'm doing multiple sql queries

      ```
         app.get("/surveys/:id/edit", function (req, res) {
         var q =
         "\
          SELECT * FROM inference_db.surveys WHERE surveys.slug=?; \
          SELECT * FROM inference_db.imagez; \
          SELECT city_id, name, province  FROM inference_db.cities WHERE cities.type != 1;"
          connection.query(q, [req.params.id], function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(results[0]);
            console.log("------------participating cities-----------------   ");
            console.log(results[0].participating_cities);
            res.render("edit.ejs", {
                   pageTitle: "xdit Survey",
                   items1: results[0], // survey
                   items2: results[1], // imagez
                   items3: results[2] // cities
             });

            });
         });
      ```
   3. When I console log results[0], it is working and gives me all the fields.
   4. But when I console log results[0].participating_cities, i get undefined. I need that field because I will pass it as an array. That field is a string stored in mysql table. Can anyone please help. Thanks!

My console log:
`topic_id: 1,
                featured: 1,
                   image: 'imee_marcos.jpg',
                    slug: 'test-html-Mar-06-2019',
                  status: '1',
    participating_cities: '30,40',
    participating_groups: '2,3' } ]
------------participating cities-----------------
undefined`

[image: console log pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`results` will be an array of query results for each of the queries you ran; but each of those results is an array in itself. So you probably want to check out the value of `results[0][0].participating_cities` if you want to get that field from the first row of the first result.